# What do you call those inclined slopes surrounding for instance a tree?

Tags: single-word-requests

For a visual, you approach a tree and around it the ground slopes downward in a circular circumference and thus is not level?

"As I ran past the tree my foot got caught in the _____ and I stumbled."

Comment: Hump, lump, hill?  There is no established term, except perhaps within the jargon of landscapers.

Comment: You might be talking about [root flare](https://www.dirtdoctor.com/www/default/ckfinder/userfiles/1114/images/Newsletter%20photos/6.1.17%20-%20Root%20Flare%20Exposure/Photo_025.jpeg)

Comment: Mounds? ..................

Comment: It seems to me that OP is talking about a depression like an irrigation well around a tree.  Note how it is described as the ground slopes *downward* as you approach a tree.

Comment: @JIm the OP doesn't say whether the downward slope is towards the tree or away from it. An idiomatic expression would be "caught in the roots", even if that is not literally true.

Comment: @alephzero - No, but if I were describing what the ground looked like as I was approaching the tree and it was rising in that direction I probably wouldn’t call it downward sloping. It would be upward sloping.

Comment: @alephzero - also note that his foot got caught ***in*** something not ***on*** something as would be expected with a hump or mound.

Comment: @Jim every upward slope is also a downward slope. Almost nothing about the Op's description is unambiguous, apart from 'circular circumference' of course :) personally, absent reference to a tree I would expect a downward slope on a circular circumference to be a circular or spiral ramp, which clearly isn't the case here.

Comment: @RGK could you find us a picture of exactly what you are talking about? In unpaved ground most trees don't really make any kind of mound or depression in the ground as they grow, though the roots may flare out at the base causing some fluting. In *paving* though, they can lift the paving as they grow, and because the paving, be it blocks or tar, is a solid layer it gets moved aside rather than moved through. In the case of lifted paving, I'd call it lifted paving.

Comment: These are examples of what I’m envisioning: Image from http://www.aicrppalms.res.in/img/achievements/cp1.jpg   Image from http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-c3jiEKinRrg/VlTNzAHolsI/AAAAAAAAr_w/1XS2IfLVggk/s1600/pine%2Btree%2Birrigation%2Bbubbler%2Bbasin%2B%25281%2529.JPG  Image from https://www.syntheticgrasswarehouse.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/02-500x397.jpg

Comment: [Mulch volcanoes](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&q=mulch+volcanoes+around+trees&oq=trees%2C+mulch+volvanoes&gs_l=psy-ab.1.0.0i8i13i30k1.2393.16699.0.19609.23.22.0.0.0.0.213.3835.0j19j2.21.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..2.19.3461.0..0j46j0i131k1j0i46k1j0i10k1j0i22i30k1j33i160k1j0i13i10i30k1j0i13i5i30k1.fgumtgKJ1eI) are the opposite of what @Jim pictured.  So, dear OP, do you mean sloping up towards the trunk (mulch volcanoes) or down from the trunk (???) ?

Comment: @ab2 - *basins, tree basins, irrigation basins*...

Comment: Until 7 hours ago the OP was online, but despite numerous comments posted by many different users asking for more detail/information and clarification, the OP has kept silent. Therefore, I am casting my vote to close this question as being unclear. There are now 4 votes in favour of closing, only one more is needed and then it is "closed". Predictably, the OP will probably become upset and annoyed that his Q is put on hold.